# Superior knowledge needed in OOP before Data structures?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm struggling implementing the data structures from my book into formal usable code. I'm starting to believe that it is my ignorance in OOP concepts such as inheritance.

I understand how data structures such as linked list, trees, and some graphing concepts work conceptually, but even after using and debugging people's code online. I get lost in the class/header files and the inheritance they used.

So, I was wondering if a strong knowledge of how OOP works is necessary to learn data structures? The basics such as constructors and destructor are fairly simple, but concepts such as passing pointer objects into another class object gets wildly confusing.

Any input from experience on what helped you the most when learning data structures and what knowledge you felt was necessary when learning it would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Data structures can be implemented in a non-OOP fashion, so OOP knowledge is not a prerequisite. Having classes can certainly make it easier, but it's not necessary.

Comment: I am voting to close as "Subjective" - people can claim to one approach or the other. My general *opinion* is no - Abstract Data Types can be implemented without any knowledge on OOP - but again, it is an opinion.

Comment: I think you need to decouple data structures from OOP. If you are dealing with data structures implemented with OOP techniques, then obviously you need an understanding of OOP. But this isn't limited to data structures. On the other hand, you can find data structure implementations that use no OOP techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, knowledge of OOP is not needed to understand data structures. Data structures exist even in languages with no OOP support. It may depend on which data structures you mean and in which language you want to implement them.